# Парсер возвращает none. Как исправить это?

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, beautiful-soup

Вот мой код. Это парсер вакансий, он находит имена вакансии.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxProfile
from selenium import webdriver
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import time
user=UserAgent()
profile=webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('general.useragent.override',user.random)
driver=webdriver.Firefox(profile)
driver.get('https://rabota.ykt.ru/') 

#Это смена юзер агента
time.sleep(10)

def rabota(navigate):
    soup=BeautifulSoup(navigate,'lxml')
    vacansii=soup.findAll(class_='class="r-vacancy_list_item ng-scope')
    all_knopki=[]
    for vacansia in vacansii:
        knopka=vacansia.find(class_='r-vacancy_title').text
        all_knopki.append(knopka)
        return all_knopki
    #Это нахождение названий вакансий
def navigate():
    table=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('ul.r-vacancy_list').get_attribute('innerHTML')
    return table
    #Это нахождение всей таблицы селениумом, где хранятся вакансии
def main():
    a=rabota(navigate())
    print (a)


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Парсер возвращает None , в чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: для этого сайта хватит `requests`+`bs4`, `selenium` тут не нужен. Если вам не принципиально использовать `selenium`, то лучше написать это на `requests`+`bs4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправьте строку `vacansii=soup.findAll(class_='class="r-vacancy_list_item ng-scope')` на эту
`vacansii=soup.findAll(class_='r-vacancy_list_item ng-scope')`